# mongoose & node js findOne And Update query promise not resolving in loop

Tags: node.js, mongoose

we are trying to read the bulk of xml files under a directory which have a list of data(around 50K objects) and check in DB each record and insert if not exists. After completing one file data, it should go for second file, which is not all happeing. Below is the code what we written.

FYI: we recently starting working on node, mongoose and started writing a script the cron job.

```js
    ## we recently starting working on node, mongoose and started writing a script the cron job.

    var fs = require('fs');
    function log(arg) {
        console.log(arg);
    }
     
    ## step-1: read the files in dir
    fs.readdir('./scripts/test/', function(err, files) {
        files.filter(fn => fn.endsWith('.xml')).forEach(file => {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fs.readFile('/scripts/test/'+file, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        log('parsing XML to JSON.....');
                        resolve(data);
                    } else {
                        log('reading file error: '+err)
                        reject(err);
                    }
                });
            }).then((data) => {
                var productData = JSON.parse(data);
                ## calling another function
                format(productData);
            }).catch(err => log('Catch Error: '+err)); 
        });
    });

    async function format(items) {
        if (productData !== undefined) {
            await productBatchesloop(items);
            log('completed');
        } else {
            log('@@@@@@@ action:productData undefined @@@@@@@@');
        }
    }

    async function productBatchesloop(items) {
        var formatted_products, items_batch, promises;
        formatted_products = promises = []; var next = 1;

        var formatfn = function formatItems(product) {
            let pro = ProductModel.findOneAndUpdate(
                {id: product.id},
                product,
                {upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true}).exec();
            pro.then((pro) => {
                log('inserted: '+pro.id);
            });
            log(pro);//not waiting for resolve, showing Promise <pending>
        }

        var res2 = Promise.all(items.map(formatfn));
        res2.then((data) => {
            log('*********** COMPLETED **************');
            // log(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Promises aren't awaited by the `forEach` since it's synchronous. Put your promises in an array and do `Promise.all` on that instead.

Comment: Also the `new Promise` looks superfluous since `fs.readFile` is async.

Comment: I have put all the query promises in `promises` array and used the Promise.all(promises), still it's not waiting to resolve all the promises and going to next iteration.

code:
let pro = await ProductModel.findOne({id: product.id});
promises.push(pro);
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    log('*********** COMPLETED **************');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    log(err);
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async await in the mongoose query.

```
var formatfn = async formatItems(product) => {
            let pro = await ProductModel.findOneAndUpdate(
                {id: product.id},
                product,
                {upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true}).exec();
            pro.then((pro) => {
                log('inserted: '+pro.id);
            });
            log(pro);//not waiting for resolve, showing Promise <pending>
        }
```

Comment: Still, it's not working. without waiting for resolving, it's going for next iteration